# How to use Docker container name for URL endpoint in React app when building app with docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express, docker-compose

Recently I'm working with a MERN stack application. Then I have a docker-compose.yml look like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: ./concept.io-frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - network.concept.io
    container_name: concept.io
  api:
    build: ./concept.io-backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5328:5328"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - network.concept.io
    container_name: api.concept.io
  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - network.concept.io
    container_name: db.concept.io
networks:
  network.concept.io:
    driver: bridge
```

So in the backend (Express) code, I wrote:

```
const URL = "mongodb://db.concept.io:27017/conceptio";

module.exports = {
  url: URL,
};
```

The API container connects flawlessly with Mongo one when I declare that API container depends on Mongo container.

But when it comes to the frontend container, I have reproduced the same setup, which frontend container depends on the API container, and replace the "localhost" with the container name as the API and Mongo ones.

```
// const URL = "http://localhost:5328/";
const URL = "http://api.concept.io:5328/";
export const API_URL = URL + "api/";
export const AUTH_URL = API_URL + "auth/";
```

But I can't make a request to that endpoint.

Is there any mistake or any idea to make HTTP Request to another container in the same network of Docker containers?

Here are Dockerfiles:

API:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.12 as builder
RUN apk add yarn

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 5328

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Frontend:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.12 AS builder
RUN apk add yarn

WORKDIR /opt/web
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

COPY . ./
RUN yarn run build

FROM nginx:1.19.1-alpine
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl -L https://github.com/a8m/envsubst/releases/download/v1.2.0/envsubst-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o envsubst && \
    chmod +x envsubst && \
    mv envsubst /usr/local/bin
COPY ./nginx.config /etc/nginx/nginx.template
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
COPY --from=builder /opt/web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Does that front-end code run inside the container, or is it serving up a browser application and the browser is ultimately calling the URL you show?  The browser does not run inside the Docker network and can't use the Docker-private hostnames.

Comment: @DavidMaze just got it. the browser cannot translate Docker hostnames so I just can go with localhost or modify the hosts file to make a fake domain. thanks :D

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the virtual host inside the docker-compose.yml

environment:
VIRTUAL_HOST: concept.io

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: see the below post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164716/docker-compose-virtual-hosts

Comment: just got it. config a fake hostname/domain is the way to go :D Thanks.

Comment: This does not answer the question